# Don't know what file need to edit to insert public token key in a c# project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, token

I'm trying to run [This open source project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eraser/?source=directory) downloaded from sourceforge. I'm getting the same error seven times, when I import the project it says it need the public token file:

```
\Eraser.Util.csproj : error  : Can't find the file or asembled Microsoft.Build, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or its dependencies. System cannot find specified file.
```

[image]

[image]
After googling, I've found in a web application the solution to this same problem is to edit web.config and add there the public token key. I've been looking in my project and there is no such file, I need to add this public token key somewere to be able to run this project. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate more: What did you use to create the project VS or? How are you referencing the dll or such etc?

Comment: it's a project downloaded from sourceforge.net. I've imported it in visual studio 2012 profesional, because I've tried with 2013 2015 and there was other errors... So i've donwloaded this one and now it looks to be working except I need the public token key. I've been googling and in a web app case the web.config file must be edited to add the token key. In this case I think it's a matter to edit a dll file, but don't have a clue of which one I must edit.

Comment: You don't edit a dll- a dll is a dynamic link library. You just have to make sure it's reference in your project.